# Camel consuming twitter timeline tweets, and rates

Tags: java, twitter, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I am trying to get tweets from my *Twitter* timeline with `ConsumerTemplate` (Camel) in a *Quarkus* app.

I don't understand how it should be done correctly **while using rate limits** (my free account has rate 15 polls in 5 min).

The *Camel* setup has property count which I set to `10`, and expect to get `10` new tweets in one poll, but the problem is that template offers only one tweet per *Camel* request:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

    // I would expect here List or stream, but I can get only single `Status`
    final Status tweets = consumerTemplate.receiveBodyNoWait(String.format("twitter-timeline://home?sinceId=%s&count=10", sinceId), Status.class);

    // just to show that I change that property
    if (nonNull(tweets)) {
         sinceId = tweets.getId();
    }

}
```

So my question is why I get only one tweet per poll even if count is set (a value more than `1`). Is there any better way or running that template, or something I can use instead while respecting downstream *Twitter* rate limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConsumerTemplate` is based on a `PollingConsumer` under the hood, which as the name implies, pulls `Exchage`s one at a time hence why you are receiving only 1 `Status` (== 1 `Exchange`) even while setting a `count` endpoint option.

It is almost hard (and error-prone) to implement tweets (or other `Exchange`s) consumption the right way. Indeed this is already offered out-of-the-box with the *Apache Camel* *Twitter Component* consumer.

Here down a sample of a route to consume **user** public activity (timeline) using the [*twitter-timeline* component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/twitter-timeline-component.html):

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
            https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <route id="twitter-timeline" autoStartup="true">
        <from uri="twitter-timeline:USER?user=some-user&amp;consumerKey=your-app-key&amp;consumerSecret=your-app-key-secret&amp;accessToken=your-app-access-token&amp;accessTokenSecret=your-app-access-token-secret"/>
        <log message="${body}"/>
    </route>

</routes>
```

This will leverage the default *polling* configured delays which you can tweak based on your preferences to address any rate-limits. In your case for example, to respect 15 requests per 5 mins, you can set the consumer to poll each 20 seconds **for one page**:

```
<from uri="twitter-timeline:USER?user=some-user&amp;count=100&amp;numberOfPage=1&amp;delay=20000"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! It is very helpful, I have posted my solution in Quarkus maybe it would be helpful for someone else.

Comment: You're welcome @GarionS.. You mean the Java DSL based declaration of the route and not *Quarkus* one. I should have pointed out that there is different DSLs to configure the route but the Apache Camel documentation is very compact and has all the information you would need.

Answer (score 1):

Based on tmarwen's answer in Quarkus I managed to do it without XML, and with increased delay (seems ratio was smaller for API v1.1):

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TimelineService extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        fromF("twitter-timeline://home?count=100&numberOfPages=1&delay=180000&consumerKey=%s&consumerSecret=%s&accessToken=%s&accessTokenSecret=%s",
                apiKey, apiKeySecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
                .setBody(exchange -> {
                    // Status - can cast or manipulate
                    Object body = exchange.getMessage().getBody();
                    return body;
                })
                .to("log:twitter?showExchangePattern=false&showBodyType=false");
    }
}
```